# Change citation style from square brackets to forward slashes

Tags: citing

In latex, how can I change citation style from square brackets (e.g. "As authors in [1] show ...") to forward slashes ("As authors in /1/ show ...")?

**EDIT** To answer the comments below... I don't know the name of citation style. It is just a requirement of MSc thesis formatting.

**Main document (dissertation.tex) looks like that**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\input{packages}        
\input{styles}          
\input{data}            
\begin{document}
\input{introduction}   
\input{part1}          
\input{references}     
\end{document}
```

**The command used to generate pdf**

```
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="xelatex %O %S" dissertation
```

**EDIT 2** Bibliography style, the style is defined here (https://github.com/AndreyAkinshin/Russian-Phd-LaTeX-Dissertation-Template/blob/master/Synopsis/utf8gost71u.bst)

```
\bibliographystyle{utf8gost71u} 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a *full* minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Is easier for us in this way can help you copiyng and running code instead watch a screenshot.

Comment: Which citation style are using you? What has to do latex3 with this?

Comment: Actually: one of those `\input` calls **is** deciding what citation style you are using, and we can't answer your question until you figure out what it is.  Look for a command like `\bibliographystyle` or a call to a package by the name of `biblatex`. There's a good chance one of those two are responsible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the [cite package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite):

```
\usepackage{cite}
\def\citeleft{/}
\def\citeright{/}
```

I think it's quite self-explanatory:)

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, here's a solution that's based on the `natbib` citation management package:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{/}{/}{;}{n}{}{,}
```

The result of a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myxyz.bib}
@article{xyz,
  author = "Anne Author",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  journal= "Circularity Today",
  volume = 1,
  number = 2,
  pages  = "3-4",
  year   = 5001,
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % no access to "utf8gost71u.bst"
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{/}{/}{;}{n}{}{,}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{xyz}

\bibliography{myxyz}
\end{document}
```