# Change citation style from square brackets to forward slashes with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

How can I change the style of citation in Biblatex from [1] to /1/ in both citing within the document as well as in the references at the end of the document?
I found some Information ragarding changes for [BibTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239379/change-citation-style-from-square-brackets-to-forward-slashes), but not for BibLaTex.
I also managed to change it to [backslashes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307038/change-citation-style-from-square-brackets-to-backslashes-with-biblatex).

MWE for standard numeric-comp:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{spiegelberg}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy if you don't need to change `\textcite` as well

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibpairedslashes}[1]{/#1/}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibpairedslashes{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibpairedslashes{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibpairedslashes]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\cite{spiegelberg}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]